# Copy files from a docker image to another

Tags: docker, copy

I need to hide my base code from the user. So I decided to just copy all files into a docker image and import those files from that image later.

```
# Use a base image (you can specify any base image that suits your needs)
 FROM ubuntu:latest

# Set the working directory inside the container
 WORKDIR /app

# Copy the files from the local machine to the container
COPY . /app
```

If I do like that can I copy these files in another docker file when I needed? If yes how can we do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`COPY --from`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy) with any image, not just other stages in your current Dockerfile.

```bash
FROM python:3.11
COPY --from=registry.example.com/source-only-image /app /app
WORKDIR /app
CMD ["./main.py"]
```

Once you do this the files will be present in the destination image and you can do anything with them you could with files in a Docker image, like `docker run ... cat` them or `docker cp` them to the host.  That is, there is no security benefit to doing things this way.